# Android - constantly updating fragment UI?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-xml

I've got a fully working activity. However, I want to adapt the activity to a Fragment so I'm able to transition between the initial activity and any future activities.

However, how do I update the UI after I've called the `onCreateView();`?  I've got a task that is repeated constantly by a handler, so the interface needs to be updated every 0.5 seconds. This doesn't seem possible with a fragment as it seems to be static (it's exited after creation).

So how do I edit/update a fragment's interface after it's creation?
Do I do my activity's work inside the FragmentActivity or the Fragment itself?

Comment: If you can post some of the code, like, method updates UI. Then we can see how we can help. And the other thing is, where do you update the UI ? inside from fragment or outside of the fragment ?

Comment: Droidman posted the correct answer down below. His answer should be marked as checked...

Answer (score 2):

1) in your `Fragment`, init `Views` in the `onCreateView()` method, use class fields

2) create public methods inside your `Fragment` and you can call them from `Activity`

```
 yourFragInstance.yourMethod();
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this a whole day and didn't get it working... I don't know what's going wrong with me or the fragments, but my question is 'Are you 100% complete sure that it will work?'

Comment: @MartinPfeffer this is the way I do it. If it doesn't work for you, I guess your `Fragment` instance is `null` which means it's not correctly referenced

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :) Hmm, that could be possible. Do you declare your variables (the View object which is returned in onCreateView() e.g.) as static?

Comment: @MartinPfeffer nope, that's a wrong way to do it. Here's an example taken out from one of my projects http://pastebin.com/b0LP3avq

Comment: This looks like a proper solution to me. I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah brother, with your help I found the stupid bug: I only made the 'not-null' check with the Fragment object, which I create in the 'Fragment-hosting-MainActivity'. The issue was that the object is created but not the view by itself. At the end I put a boolean in the end of onCreateView and set up a getter which returns it. Following this way, MainActivity knows if it is possible to invoke methods which interact with View-objects inside Fragment (TextView, ImageView) I was close to lose my teeth while biting my device - but with your convincing clear answer I get the right motivation. Thanks